# Find $E_\eta$ and $D_\eta$ if $\eta = e^\xi$ and $\xi$ has normal distribution $N(a, \sigma^2)$

Tags: calculus, integration, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let we have $\xi$ which has normal distribution $N(a, \sigma^2)$

And also let's define $\eta=e^\xi$. I want to find $E_\eta$ and $D_\eta$ for this random value.

Here's what I've got:

I can find $E_\xi$ and $D_\xi$ because I know that for $\xi$: $$p(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}e^{\frac{(x - a)^2}{2\sigma^2}}$$ and then we can evaluate that $$E_\xi = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xp(x) \ dx$$

Same things for disperson and I've got that $$D_\xi = E_{\xi^2} - E_\xi^2 = (a^2 + \sigma^2) - a^2 = \sigma^2$$

But how can I use it to evaluate $E_\eta$ and $D_\eta$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\xi\sim N(a,\sigma^2)$, then $\eta=e^{\xi}$ has a log-normal distribution with:
$E(\eta)=e^{a+\frac{\sigma^2}{2}}$
$E(\eta^2)=e^{2a+2 \sigma^2}$
$Var(\eta)=E(\eta^2)-E(\eta)^2=E(\eta)^2(e^{\sigma^2}-1)=e^{2a+\sigma^2}(e^{\sigma^2}-1)$